# Display row count result per page in gridview - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview1 that has a page size 20 per page, and I bind it with a data with a total of 59 results, so it has 3 pages, the third page has 19 rows.

I know how to display the row count (20 (p1),20(p2),19(p3)) and the total count which is 59, but how can I achieve this result?

```
1 is 20
2 is 21~40
3 is 41~59
```

Where page 1 will display 20, as its first result, and 21~40 on the second page and 41~59 to the 3rd page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement Virtual Paging which will bind only 20 rows to grid and show total number of records in grid footer.

Comment: how can I implement this virtual paging? can you provide an easy to understand link on how to do it please?

Comment: You can visit link. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/